# I have Directx11, but can't run dx 10 games

Tags: directx

I've installed the June 2010 SDK, the redistributables, and done everything I know how.

I've downloaded directx 2010 tutorials, when they compile I get a `can not initialize direct 3d` error. When I run directx11 sdk, I can compile and initialize them fine.

But I have a computer game that runs DX10 and I get the same 'not not initialize direct 3d' error there. Which is the only reason I want to fix this issue so I can go back to playing this game.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I right clicked on the EXE and ran as integrated graphics which is my intel 4000 and now I get "CreateTextureFailed" instead of can not initialize directx3d.

```
Operating System: Windows 8.1 64-bit (6.3, Build 9600) (9600.winblue_gdr.140723-2018)
Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
System Manufacturer: SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO., LTD.
System Model: 700Z7C
BIOS: Phoenix BIOS SC-T v2.2 P06AAE
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3615QM CPU @ 2.30GHz (8 CPUs), ~2.3GHz
Memory: 8192MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 7974MB RAM
Page File: 3671MB used, 8013MB available
Windows Dir: C:\Windows
DirectX Version: DirectX 11
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
DxDiag Version: 6.03.9600.16384 64bit Unicode

Secondary Video Card which I set to primary is NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M





[Display]
Operating System:   Windows 8.1, 64-bit
DirectX version:    11.0 
GPU processor:   GeForce GT 650M
Driver version:  347.52
Direct3D API version:   11.2
Direct3D feature level: 11_0
CUDA Cores:  384 
Core clock:  745 MHz 
Memory data rate:   4000 MHz
Memory interface:   128-bit 
Memory bandwidth:   64.00 GB/s
Total available graphics memory:    4096 MB
Dedicated video memory: 2048 MB GDDR5
System video memory:    0 MB
Shared system memory:   2048 MB
Video BIOS version: 80.07.39.00.14
IRQ:     16
Bus:     PCI Express x16 Gen2
Device Id:   10DE 0FD1 C0CC144D
Part Number:     1304 0020

[Components]

NvUpdtr.dll  17.12.8.0   NVIDIA Update Components
NvUpdt.dll   17.12.8.0   NVIDIA Update Components
NvGFTrayPluginr.dll  17.12.8.0   NVIDIA GeForce Experience
NvGFTrayPlugin.dll   17.12.8.0   NVIDIA GeForce Experience
nvui.dll     8.17.13.4752    NVIDIA User Experience Driver Component
nvxdsync.exe     8.17.13.4752    NVIDIA User Experience Driver Component
nvxdplcy.dll     8.17.13.4752    NVIDIA User Experience Driver Component
nvxdbat.dll  8.17.13.4752    NVIDIA User Experience Driver Component
nvxdapix.dll     8.17.13.4752    NVIDIA User Experience Driver Component
NVCPL.DLL    8.17.13.4752    NVIDIA User Experience Driver Component
nvCplUIR.dll     8.1.760.0   NVIDIA Control Panel
nvCplUI.exe  8.1.760.0   NVIDIA Control Panel
nvWSSR.dll   6.14.13.4752    NVIDIA Workstation Server
nvWSS.dll    6.14.13.4752    NVIDIA Workstation Server
nvViTvSR.dll     6.14.13.4752    NVIDIA Video Server
nvViTvS.dll  6.14.13.4752    NVIDIA Video Server
nvDispSR.dll     6.14.13.4752    NVIDIA Display Server
NVMCTRAY.DLL     8.17.13.4752    NVIDIA Media Center Library
nvDispS.dll  6.14.13.4752    NVIDIA Display Server
PhysX    09.14.0702  NVIDIA PhysX
NVCUDA.DLL   8.17.13.4752    NVIDIA CUDA 7.0.23 driver
nvGameSR.dll     6.14.13.4752    NVIDIA 3D Settings Server
nvGameS.dll  6.14.13.4752    NVIDIA 3D Settings Server
```

Answer (score 1):

Running games today is not as easy as one may think.
DX is only part of the problem.
Make sure your driver is also up to date, with nv physix included.
Make sure you have all updates of DX9, since some games will require much of it even if they run in DX10/11 mode.

What games do not work for you ?

Check this guide [here](https://xaeus.wordpress.com/2013/08/31/how-to-make-games-actually-work-en/) to see everything you should have installed in order to run any DX8+ based game without problems.

Don't try to run too many DX tests on the intel. Intel video cards are not for games.

Comment: I have the latest drivers of everything. I have PhysX installed, its running in the control panel. What games, so far anything with directx 9 or 10. Even the SDK samples

Comment: As I said, some files (like d3dx9_43.dll) are used by those games. You need to update DX9. Note that Windows 8.1 also doesn't include in-box, third-party GPU drivers for nVidia DirectX 9.x families. Instead, drivers are provided via Dynamic Update during the windows installation / upgrade process, or via Windows Update after the installation. Also, get the end user DX runtime: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8109 .

Comment: I see in the crash log that this game is using d3dx10_43.dll and d3dCOMPILER_43.dll; I have both of these in my windows system folder. I did just notice though, after uninstalling my nvidia card the game ran with the integrated graphics card without an error, but unplayable lag. I'm running the link you just sent me now, hopefully it'll install.

Comment: It ran, I installed it. Same error when launching my game.

Comment: It means it could be a problem with switching from default intel card to your nV. Go to nvidia control panel, select manage 3d settings, in there, go to Global Settings tab switch the drop down from Auto to nvidia. Restart. The setting may also be called  Preferred Graphics Processor. This should allow all users to run the system on the Nvidia GPU with correct access privileges  whenever required.

Comment: I tried that one, same error.

Comment: In that case you should uninstall everything video-driver related, including the intel's, chipset, phyix, etc, cleanup registry and then install latest version of MB driver (chipset + onboard video), then nV driver (keep physx out for now, just for testing purposes). Also, when you do, try driver version 332.21 instead of the latest (347.nn).

Comment: I just tried all that and downgraded to 332.21, I tried running the game and got another error exception violation. When I uninstalled the nvidia driver the game ran ran, but was using the slow intel graphics card. This is frustrating.

Comment: Well clearly nV drivers are at fault, but in combination with operating system settings. If uninstalling all drivers, doing a system cleanup for junk registry entries and junk nV dlls (driver cleaner pro should do for this) and putting them back won't work, then the solution that remains is to reinstall windows.

Comment: I'm installing windows 10 now hopefully this will work

Comment: Be aware that x64 version may generate installation errors when installed UEFI mode. I tested both x64 and x86 versions, but not for games (for now).